# "Receiving end does not exist" when passing message to injected content script

Tags: javascript, promise, listener, message, firefox-addon-webextensions

In an add-on for Firefox, I'm trying to inject code from a background script into a tab and then pass a message to it. Unfortunately, the content script seems to add the listener only after the message has already been sent, resulting in in error. What am I missing? Here is my sample code:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "description": "Test background to content message passing",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Background content message passing",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "default_locale": "en",

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
            "id": "bcm@example.com",
            "strict_min_version": "51.0"
        }
    },

    "permissions": [
        "contextMenus",
        "<all_urls>"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    }
}
```

background.js:

```
"use strict";

const {contextMenus, i18n, runtime, tabs} = browser;

contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "bgd-cnt-msg") {
        tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: "/content.js",
        })
        .then(runtime.sendMessage({"result": 42}))
        .then(console.log("Debug: runtime message sent"))
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    }
});

contextMenus.create({
    id: "bgd-cnt-msg",
    title: "Test message passing",
    contexts: ["all"],
    documentUrlPatterns: ["<all_urls>"]
});
```

content.js

```
"use strict";

console.log("Debug: executing content script");

browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    console.log("Debug: received message %O", message);
});

console.log("Debug: added listener");
```

The result of selecting the the context menu entry is

```
Debug: runtime message sent                                  background.js:11:15
Debug: executing content script                                     content.js:3
Debug: added listener                                               content.js:9
Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.   undefined
```

I.e., the context scripts executes after the message to the tab is sent. How can I add the listener before sending the message?

---

As suggested by @Thắng, I changed my code to use `tabs.sendMessage` instead of `runtime.sendMessage`:

```
contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "bgd-cnt-msg") {
        tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: "/content.js",
        })
        .then(tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"result": 42}))
        .then(console.log("Debug: runtime message sent"))
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    }
});
```

Now the error is reported a little earlier:

```
Debug: runtime message sent                                  background.js:11:15
Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.   undefined
Debug: executing content script                                     content.js:3
Debug: added listener                                               content.js:9
```

---

Thanks to @Thắng, who provided a working solution, I fixed my code to not only use `tabs.sendMessage` but also pass functions for the callbacks:

```
contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "bgd-cnt-msg") {
        tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
            file: "/content.js",
        })
        .then(function () { tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"result": 42}) })
        .then(function () { console.log("Debug: runtime message sent") })
        .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    }
});
```

With an additional fix in `content.js`

```
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    console.log("Debug: result is " + message.result);
});
```

I now get

```
Debug: executing content script                                     content.js:3
Debug: added listener                                               content.js:9
Debug: runtime message sent                                  background.js:11:15
Debug: result is 42                                                 content.js:6
```

Comment: Put the `contextMenus.create(...` bit before the other part?

Comment: @BaileyS Unfortunenately, that does not help.

Comment: Sorry for the lame guess :( I hope you get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In background script, you need to let it know it should send the message to which tab, so don't use `runtime.sendMessage` for this.

```
var sending = chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
  tabId,                   // integer
  message,                 // any
  options                  // optional object
)
```

See more here (for webExtensions but also compatible with Chrome): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/sendMessage

Your fully working extension here (you may need to change all the `browser.*` to `chrome.*`):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KGf8tCM1grhhiC9XcHOjsrbBsIZGff3e/view?usp=sharing